# Query Isn't Working like others

Tags: php, mysql

I for the life of me cannot figure out why this is not outputting a 0 when i try to echo it. It works on the previous query but not for the last one.

```
// This one works and if there are no movies above 0 then it outpus 0 fine
$tag_movies_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tagname='$n' AND movie > 0");
$total_times_used_movies = mysql_num_rows($tag_movies_result);

// Where as this query returns an error 
$tag_shows_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tagname='$n' AND show > 0"); <-- `show`
$total_times_used_shows = mysql_num_rows($tag_shows_result); <-- Line 12

// the error
Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/a5410474/public_html/tags/tag.php on line 12
```

this is what i use to call it

```
<li><a href="#shows" rel="shows">Shows (<?php echo $total_times_used_shows; ?>)</a></li>
```

demo: http://mydb.host56.com/tags.php?n=the

the column name SHOWS needed to be enclosed in `. Topic Closed.

Comment: After your query, add `echo mysql_error();` to see why the query is failing.

Comment: If you find the answer to your question was a syntax error, it's better to NOT correct it in the original question so future visitors can see the issue and the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SHOW is reserved keyword
wrap tilde (`)  around show, like below:

```
`show`
```

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show.html)

Answer (score 1):

If there is an error in a query, the value returned from mysql_query will be FALSE rather than a resource. Try this:

```
if(!$tag_show_result) {
 echo mysql_error();
}
```

This should help you to identify the error in the query

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I see what the problem might be. You should still add `echo mysql_error();` to the line right after the query that is failing, however there is an error in your query. the word `show` is a mysql reserved word. [Show](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show.html) is used to display information about the database. You can wrap it in backticks like this:

```
`show`
```

Answer (score 0):

There's clearly an error in your query; find that, and you will resolve the problem.

More to the point, you should be checking the result of your mysql_query for FALSE to make sure that the query was successful, and if it wasn't, output the error using mysql_error().